# AJAX request fails .zip file OnceBuilder CMS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building another full stack library but i'm so strugling on one AJAX request, which is so ridiculous. I have just found that, this function is strugling to get file archive but it can gets easly another files ( that can be solution but... i need zip file too) plugin 19 is static because it's just testing and only this file exists

```
@file_get_contents('https://oncebuilder.com/once/plugins/19/plugin.zip');
```

So basicly **both AJAX function are the same**

If i lunch the same function from preview mode file_get_contents gets crazy and return error, but if i lunch it from the listing or via browser its ok

AJAX function are both the same

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: once.path+"/ajax.php?c=plugins&o=item_download&id=19",
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json'
})
.error(function() { console.log("Request Error: item_download"); });
```

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Je0.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAeLg.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGQcy.png